# dragging and dropping a button in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to drag and drop UIButtons(image) on bigger UIImageView. I want to implement following functionality -

1. While dragging if the button is inside UIImageView then only it should drop,else it should not drop
2. When touching down and dragging it should immediately create a new UIButton at original position.
3. After the UIButton is dropped it should not move from its new position.

Thanking in advance.

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979555/iphone-drag-drop

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for but what you can do is **start a timer on the touchDown** action that will trigger a method that makes the button update to the **current CGPoint touch location**. Then add **if statements to control whether it's inside an image or not.** To make the button stop, use the touchUpInside method and **invalidate the timer.**