# how to move circle in screen game

Tags: iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Drag and drop UIViews with Box2d (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886827/drag-and-drop-uiviews-with-box2d-ios)

create circle at bottom of screen if I touch down on circle,it will go on to top of screen and if I touch up,it falls down to bottom of screen.how can i create this type of game? Anybody have some tutorials regarding to this type of game then give me tutorials.Thanks in advance